# Android Studio MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, android-studio

I'm struggling with this problem for days now and I just can't come up with a good answer. I'm trying to get some live feed from my database like AJAX does, whenever I edit something in the database the app needs to adjust it current values to the ones in the database.

However I can't find anything about this without using PHP. Do you know an answer ?

Comment: Can your app just poll the server via HTTP every five minutes? How often do you need it to be updated? (Consider the user's data plain here, of course).

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier for your app to poll your database than the other way around. You could make an http request in the onStart() portion of your activity to give your users fresh info.

If you need your app's data updated even when they are not using it, and/or want to create notifications then Google Cloud Messaging is the way to go. Another option is that you set up an alarm and intent service to poll your database every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting frequently might be a bad idea. You can use sockets for this purpose. It'll fit your needs.